# html to pdf including MathJax transformation

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfbox, mathjax

How do I create a pdf with html (DOM) content accounting for the `css styles` of html?
HTML has [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) javascript rendered formulae in it. I would like the pdf to show the formulae as they are visible in browser using `MathJax`.
Also, HTML contains few images.
Which open source java library helps to create such a pdf from html content?
I looked into `Apache PdfBox` but did not find a solution.
Solution has to be open source library to be used in commercial application.

**EDIT**
DOM content is dynamic generated on server side and not pushed to browser.
[FlyingSaucer](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html) is close to what I need. However this does not support java script i.e html with  MathJax can not be (properly) converted to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

There are various PDF renderers based on WebKit that support JavaScript. The best I've found is the screen capture feature of PhantomJS.

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

You'll have to write a bit of code though, and make sure you don't take the screen grab until the JS has finished doing its thing.

---

**Update**
Here's a really simple example that reads HTML from stdin and saves a PDF file to disk:

```
// render.js
var page = new WebPage();
page.content = require("system").stdin.read();

setTimeout( function(){
    page.render( 'export.pdf' );
    phantom.exit(0);
}, 100 ); // <- wait for JS
```

You can execute this from whatever server-side runtime you're using, as long as it can execute a shell. To test it from the command line with a static file, you can do:

```
~/bin/phantomjs render.js < sample.html
```

Comment: Thnx. DOM content is dynamic generated on server side and not pushed to browser.

Comment: It doesn't need a browser. This is the point. You just pipe HTML to it and it gives you a PDF back

Comment: Cool. I will explore for its Java equivalent. My application runtime is JVM. ( A web app deployed to Tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

To render a MathJax formula in a PDF converted from a HTML document. You need a browser render or at least something that can execute the javascript that will render the formula.

You could use the open source https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ that can handle HTML to PDF conversion and mathJax render.

There is also some paid API like https://pdftoolkitapi.com/ that do it all.